# Apply condition to multiple columns with indexing in R

Tags: r, indexing, conditional-statements

I have a cool school assignment where we have to perform some web scraping to scrape the best 480 players on Fifa Ultimate Team (FUT). All their names and statistics are stored in a data frame. We need to create a function that filters players based on their stats (e.g. an overall player rating of over 90). I created the following function:

```
player_filter <- function(stats,minimum){
  print(Stats.FUT$Name[Stats.FUT[,stats]>=minimum])
}
```

Argument 'stats' is a vector 1:7 that I want to use to refer to the columns of my data frame with player statistics (1 being overall rating, 2 shooting, 3 dribbling and so on.)

player_filter(1,90) returns the players with a overall rating of over 90.
player_filter(3,90) returns the players with a dribbling rating of over 90.
This works well.

However, if I want to see the players that have an overall AND dribbling rating of over 90, the function fails.

player_filter(c(1,3),90) gives me the correct names of players with an overall rating of 90 (column 1), but returns NA for the other players (column 3).

It seems like it doesn't check if both column 1 and 3 comply to the minimum of 90, but checks the first column and disregards(?) the third column.

What am I doing wrong and why?

Kind regards,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Stats.FUT[,8][Stats.FUT[,1]>=90 && Stats.FUT[,3]>=90]
```

In my experience, this should work well. I can't test it, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Érico. I think a single '&' works too, but it's not the solution I'm looking for. I'm looking for a solution where I apply the condition to multiple columns, referring to them with the c (combine) function.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-created a dataframe that (I think) mirrors the format of yours:

```
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Stats.Fut <- tribble(
  ~names, ~overall, ~shooting,
  "Lionel Messi",90,90,
  "Cristiano Ronaldo",90,90,
  "Neymar",90,90,
  "Kevin De Bruyne",90,90,
  "Robert Lewandowski",90,90,
  "Sadio Mane",90,90,
  "Mohamed Salah",90,90,
  "Kylian Mbappe",90,90,
  "Virgil van Dijk",90,90,
  "Random Player 1",5,5,
  "Random Player 2",6,6
)

Stats.Fut
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    names              overall shooting
#>    <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Lionel Messi            90       90
#>  2 Cristiano Ronaldo       90       90
#>  3 Neymar                  90       90
#>  4 Kevin De Bruyne         90       90
#>  5 Robert Lewandowski      90       90
#>  6 Sadio Mane              90       90
#>  7 Mohamed Salah           90       90
#>  8 Kylian Mbappe           90       90
#>  9 Virgil van Dijk         90       90
#> 10 Random Player 1          5        5
#> 11 Random Player 2          6        6
```

### Base R Solution

The answer by @EricoPatto is basically right, except that the `&&` returns a single Boolean, whereas `&` returns a vector of Booleans which will select the correct names as follows:

```
Stats.Fut[, 1][Stats.Fut[, 2] >= 90 & Stats.Fut[, 3] >= 90]

#> [1] "Lionel Messi"       "Cristiano Ronaldo"  "Neymar"            
#> [4] "Kevin De Bruyne"    "Robert Lewandowski" "Sadio Mane"        
#> [7] "Mohamed Salah"      "Kylian Mbappe"      "Virgil van Dijk"
```

To obtain this, OP would simply have to replace the correct column indices, as follows:

```
Stats.Fut[, 8][Stats.Fut[, 1] >= 90 & Stats.Fut[, 3] >= 90]
```

### dplyr Solution

The much better way to do this (IMO) is using column names instead of indeces. It makes the code easier to read and also ensures that the code will still run even if the columns get re-ordered. Using dplyr and column names, you could arrive at the same solution using the following:

```
Stats.Fut %>%
  filter(overall >= 90,
         shooting >= 90) %>%
  select(names)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 1
#>   names             
#>   <chr>             
#> 1 Lionel Messi      
#> 2 Cristiano Ronaldo 
#> 3 Neymar            
#> 4 Kevin De Bruyne   
#> 5 Robert Lewandowski
#> 6 Sadio Mane        
#> 7 Mohamed Salah     
#> 8 Kylian Mbappe     
#> 9 Virgil van Dijk
```

Effectively the `filter` statement here is saying to only return rows where overall score is >= 90 AND shooting score is >= 90.
This returns the names as a single column tibble (basically an enhanced data.frame). If you need the names as a vector, use `pull` instead of `select` like so:

```
Stats.Fut %>%
  filter(overall >= 90,
         shooting >= 90) %>%
  pull(names)
#> [1] "Lionel Messi"       "Cristiano Ronaldo"  "Neymar"            
#> [4] "Kevin De Bruyne"    "Robert Lewandowski" "Sadio Mane"        
#> [7] "Mohamed Salah"      "Kylian Mbappe"      "Virgil van Dijk"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Daniel. It's not exactly the solution I am looking for and this is mainly my own fault since I didn't summarize my problem correctly. I edited my original post to give extra clarification. You mirrored my data frame correctly, and I agree with you that the code is more readable with the deplyr solution. It's just that I need to refer to both columns with the c (combine) function because of the function that I created to filter players.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it myself, but thank you for the support in any case.
If anyone ever experiences a similar issue, the rowMins function from the matrixStats package offers a solution. This is a workaround to apply a single condition to multiple columns with indexing. Below an example for when I want to print players' names with at least 90 overall and shooting (columns 1 and 3). As follows:

> Stats.FUT[,10] <- rowMins(as.matrix(Stats.FUT[,c(1,3)]))

> print(Stats.FUT$Name[(Stats.FUT[,10] >= 90)

I hope it helps someone one day in the future.
Cheers